# SQLite query with Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use Python to do an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) query. I can get the desired result in SQLite using

```
SELECT Four FROM keys2 WHERE One = B
```

How do I do this in Python?

I am trying

```
c = conn.cursor()

print "Opened database successfully";
x = c.execute("SELECT Four FROM keys2 WHERE One = B")
print x

conn.close()
```

But I get the message "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: B". I'm trying to select the entry under column 4 where the one column is B. I have tried several methods to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply the value using parametrized SQL:

```
x = c.execute("SELECT Four FROM keys2 WHERE One = ?", "B")
```

The problem with the SQL you posted is that the value `B` must be quoted. So

```
x = c.execute("SELECT Four FROM keys2 WHERE One = 'B'")
```

would also have worked, but it is better to always use parametrized SQL (to guard against SQL injection) and let sqlite3 do the quoting for you.

Comment: When I run that I get the following <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x107afeab0>. Do I need to convert this type? It is a text type in sqlite.

Comment: Added print x.fetchall() and looks like it is working. Thanks